# Indentation of <ul><li>

Tags: html, css

I have a list of items and it will take up two lines or more.

[image]

When it gets longer than the width of the div, it wraps to the next line like the example below.

[image]

How can I make the second line to start in alignment with **Item1** and can be done responsively?

[image]

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><strong>List of items:</strong></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item7</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I doubt it will be possible unless you use some width calculation and render it or make it so that it will always have fixed number of items or simply use a table and move out Title in one column and data in another.

Comment: I think you'll find the problem easier (and the solution more semantic) if you move `List of items:` outside the list.

Comment: You can use 2 div, one for first li, and the next for all other items. Then you can set width and they will adjust in related div.

Comment: Semantically your first "list item" is a title and not part of the list. That should be a separate element altogether and would solve the issue.

Comment: Just use a `<table>`. First cell would be the text "Line of items." Second will be the list items.

Comment: ^ No, please don't use a `<table>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that the title of your unordered list is **List of items**. Semantically speaking, it should be moved into a [heading element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements) outside of the unordered list itself.

Then you can use flexbox on a wrapper element to vertically align its child elements (the heading and the unordered list).

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

h2, li {font-size: 16px}

h2 {flex-shrink: 0;}

h2, ul {margin: 0;}

ul {padding-left: 0.5em;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>List of items:</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li><li><a href="#">Item2</a></li><li><a href="#">Item3</a></li><li><a href="#">Item4</a></li><li><a href="#">Item5</a></li><li><a href="#">Item6</a></li><li><a href="#">Item7</a></li><li><a href="#">Item8</a></li><li><a href="#">Item9</a></li><li><a href="#">Item10</a></li><li><a href="#">Item11</a></li><li><a href="#">Item12</a></li><li><a href="#">Item13</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the text in first li doesn't change this can be done with negative text indent and padding.

```css
ul {
  text-indent: -94px;
  padding-left: 94px;
}

ul li{
  text-indent: 0;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><strong>List of items:</strong></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item7</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `If the text in first li doesn't change` this is a very shaky assumption. What about a different font family, i18n (internationalization)?

Comment: @ChrisLi Thanks but the length of word is not fixed in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answers your query.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.conteiner p {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p><strong>List of items:</strong></p>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item8</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The text "List of items" is not contextually the content of your unordered list. Semantically, if you want a cleaner HTML, I would not recommend your approach.

I recommend, simply, to keep the ul to list the content that must be listed, nothing else: no title or introduction.

[image]

```
<div id="my-ul">
  <p>List of items:</p>

  <ul>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
#my-ul {
  display: flex;
}

#my-ul p {
  width: 200px;
}

#my-ul ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#my-ul ul li {
  display: inline;
}
```